# Parse from List<String> Java

Tags: java, list, parsing, arraylist

I am attempting to parse the value of the elements in a List declared as thus:

```
 List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(dupMap.values());
```

The values are such as this:

```
a:1-2
b:3-5
```

but I want one ArrayList with the first number (i.e. 1, 3) and another with the second (i.e. 2, 5). I have this worked out... Sorta:

```
String delims= "\t"; String delim2= ":"; String delim3= "-";
String splits2[]; String splits3[]; String splits4[];
Map<String,String> dupMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(dupMap.values());
ArrayList<String> parsed2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> parsed3 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> parsed3two= new ArrayList<String>();
double uniques = uniqueList.size();
for(int a=0;a<uniques;a++){
    //this doesn't work like it would for an ArrayList
    splits2 = uniqueList.split(delim2) ;
    parsed2.add(splits2[1]);
    for(int q=0; q<splits2.length; q++){
        String change2 = splits2[q];
        if(change2.length()>2){
           splits3 = change2.split(delim3);
           parsed3.add(splits3[0]);
           String change3=splits3[q];
           if (change3.length()>2){
               splits4 = change3.split(delims);
               parsed3two.add(splits4[0]);
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

uniqueList.split does not work however and I don't know if there is a similar function for List. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of object is `dupMap`?

Comment: `split()` is a memeber of the `String` class. You can iterate through the `String`s in your list and `split()` each one then put the results into your two separate lists.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas First, your name is kind of awesome. Second, I edited my post to have the information. It seems I forgot it.

Comment: any reason why parsed2 and some others are of type ArrayList and not List?

Comment: @Code-Guru I am sorry, do you mind explaining further? I am not sure I understand. Do you mean that I can say something like this in a loop iterating x: something = uniqueList.get(x); splits2 = something.split(delim2); ?

Comment: @User I have added an answer with further details. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that all of your data is in the form `[something]:[num]-[num]`, you can use a regular expression like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([^:]*):([^-]*)-([^-]*)$");

// I assume this holds all the values:
List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(dupMap.values()); 

for (String src : uniqueList) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(src); 
    if( m.find() && m.groupCount() >= 3) {
        String firstValue = m.group(1); // value to left of :
        String secondValue = m.group(2); // value between : and -
        String thirdValue = m.group(3); // value after -

        // assign to arraylists here
    }
}
```

I didn't actually put the code in to add to the specific `ArrayList`s because I couldn't quite tell from your code which `ArrayList` was supposed to hold which value.

**Edit**

Per Code-Guru's comment, an implementation using `String.split()` would go something like this:

```
String pattern = "[:\\-]";

// I assume this holds all the values:
List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(dupMap.values()); 

for (String src : uniqueList) {
    String[] parts = src.split(pattern);
    if (parts.length == 3) {
        String firstValue = parts[1]; // value to left of :
        String secondValue = parts[2]; // value between : and -
        String thirdValue = parts[3]; // value after -

        // assign to arraylists here
    }
}
```

Both approaches are pretty much the same in terms of efficiency.

Comment: This is more complicated than necessary. Using `String.split()` can vastly simplify this code.

Comment: `split()` would require at minimum two regex calls (one for each `split()`.) If the number of strings is large enough, this is more efficient. Unless it was `.split("[:\\-]*")`, I suppose.

Comment: @Sujay In this case, there is no need for a series of splits. One call with the correct regex for the delimiters would split everything all at once.

Comment: @Code-Guru -- I've updated the answer with an example for how to use `split()` instead of straight up regexes.

Comment: @Code-Guru: I agree. I didn't think it through :(

Comment: Do you need the `*` in the regex? I think the formatting in this case only specifies a single-character delimiter.

Comment: Fat finger typo. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you mean the one in the first code example, which I presume is necessary. But since I don't know anything about the input data, including whether ":-" is a valid input, so I can't be 100% certain.

Comment: Of course, at the end of this discussion, we have basically spoon-fed the OP the answer ;-(

Comment: Yes, I meant the delimiter pattern in the second version using `split()`.

Comment: Well, it wasn't marked Homework, so we can hope the OP took the time to read and understand the code instead of just copy-pasting it.

Comment: Thanks much! I appreciate that you included both ways! I chose the first way however. I always forget about regex even though it is awesome. Also, I promise it isn't homework. I am legit just trying to learn!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, I would proceed as follows:

```
for each String in uniqueList
    parse the string into a character and two integers (probably using a single call to [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int))
    insert the first integer into an List
    insert the second integer into another List
```

This is in pseudocode. Translating into Java is left as an exercise to the reader.